browser-image-compression library fails with large images
I'm trying to implement an image upload component in React that compresses images using the browser-image-compression library. While it works fine with smaller images (5-6MB), it fails when trying to process larger images (>20MB).
Here's my implementation:
/** create preview and upload image  */
const uploadImage = async (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setIsUploading(true);
  const _file = e.target.files?.[0];
  if (_file) {
    const regex = /^(?!\.)[^\s#\[\]*?:"<>|]+(?<!\.)\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg)$/;
    const isFileNameValid = regex.test(_file.name);

    if (!isFileNameValid) {
      alert(
        `Image filename is invalid.\n1. Special characters not allowed: #, [, ], *, ?, :, ", <, >, |\n2. Filename cannot start with a period (.)\n3. Only png, jpg, jpeg extensions are allowed`,
      );
      setIsUploading(false);
      return;
    }

    const resizing_options = {
      maxSizeMB: 1,
      maxWidthOrHeight: 1920,
      useWebWorker: true,
    };

    try {
      const compressedFile = await imageCompression(_file, resizing_options);
      onChange && onChange(compressedFile);

      // Create preview
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(compressedFile);
      setIsUploading(false);
      return new Promise(() => {
        reader.onload = () => {
          if (reader.result && typeof reader.result === "string") {
            previewImgSrc?.length > 0
              ? setPreviewImgSrc([...previewImgSrc, reader.result])
              : setPreviewImgSrc([reader.result]);
          }
        };
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      alert("failed to upload image");
      setIsUploading(false);
    }
  }
};

When I try to upload a 26MB image, I get this error:
{
  isTrusted: true,
  bubbles: false,
  cancelBubble: false,
  cancelable: false,
  composed: false,
  currentTarget: null,
  defaultPrevented: false,
  eventPhase: 0,
  returnValue: true,
  srcElement: null,
  target: null,
  timeStamp: 6106.299999952316,
  type: "error"
}

I've tried adjusting maxSizeMB and maxWidthOrHeight values, but it still has errors.
The library works perfectly with images around 5-6MB, but fails with larger files. How can I handle larger images effectively?
